# Saber que tipo de dato subo en mi filefield

Tags: django, django-models

Es posible saber que tipo de dato esta subiendo el usuario en mi un campo subir archivo en un form de django, todo esto con el fin de hacer lo que hace gmail. que pone los pdf separados las imagenes separadas.

Comment: Hola. ¿Puedes mostrar tu código actual?

Answer (score 0):

deberias agregar algo de codigo para obtener la extension que sube el usuario algo asi:

```
import os
nombre_documento, extension = os.path.splitext('midocumento.docx')
print nombre_documento
print extension
#output:
midocumento
.docx
```

De esta manera obtienes la extension de tu archivo subido, mas informacion en la documentacion oficial:
[Documentacion splitext Python 2.xx](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext)

[Documentacion splitext Python 3.xx](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext)

Espero te sriva suerte !!